# Android New relic track non Network error

Tags: android, error-handling, newrelic

are there any way to track handled errors on New Relic?

Documentation says that we can track with

NewRelic.noticeNetworkFailure(...)

however I've tried to track errors which aren't from any network call and with a fake URL but I got this:

```
'java.lang.String com.newrelic.agent.android.api.common.TransactionData.getUrl()' on a null object reference
```

Other platforms like JAVA have this

```
 NewRelic.noticeError(e);
```

but the android platform does not have a method to notice a simple error.

do you know how we can send handled errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, there is way to track an error however it won't appear in you crashList.

The **notice** methods that New Relic has allow you to **notice error**. With a method like the below one you can send a notice that will appear in your **Network --> error** page

```
 public static void reportLoggedException(String message, Throwable tr) {
        long time = new Date().getTime();
        try {
            if (message.isEmpty()) {
                message = "none";
            }
            NewRelic.noticeNetworkFailure("http://" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "utf-8")+".com", "GET", time, time, new Exception(tr));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```